# Concat bits into one string

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I want to concat some bits into one. I have this method:

```
public BitArray Encode(string source)
{
    List<bool> encodedSource = new List<bool>();

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        List<bool> encodedSymbol = this.Root.Traverse(source[i], new List<bool>());
        encodedSource.AddRange(encodedSymbol);
    }

    BitArray bits = new BitArray(encodedSource.ToArray());

    return bits;
}
```

It is returning me 0/1 binary bits, now I have this code to show me the output:

```
foreach (bool bit in encoded)
{
    MessageBox.Show((bit ? 1 : 0) + "");
}
```

Now I am just showing a MessageBox for each bit, but how can I just concat all the bits into one MessageBox , it may be a silly question but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var bitString = string.Concat(encoded.Select(bit => bit ? "1" : "0"))
```

Answer (score 1):

use StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder(encoded.Count)
foreach (bool bit in encoded)
{
    tmp.Append(bit ?"1": "0"));
}
MessageBox.Show(tmp.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

This visualizes what you need to do:

It's basically going trough all entries and adding either a "1" or a "0" to the list, depending on the entry.

```
    public static string ConcatList(List<bool> list)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (bool b in list)
        {
            builder.Append(b == true ? "1" : "0";
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method on `BitArray` which should do the trick:

```
public static class BitArrayExtensions
{
    public static string ToBitString(this BitArray encoded)
    {
        if (encoded == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder(encoded.Count);

        foreach (bool bit in encoded)
        {
            sb.Append(bit ? "1" : "0");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

use in your code as such:

```
MessageBox.Show(encoded.ToBitString());
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
string bitString = string.Empty;
foreach (bool bit in encodedSource)
{
  bitString = string.Concat(bitString, (bit ? "1" : "0"));
}
```

Comment: Potential performance problem with all the string concats. The other answers with `StringBuilder` avoid that.